# Restore from xp windows\Prefetch\WINWORD.EXE-2......5.pf OR WINRAR.EXE-3......8.pf

Tags: windows, ms-word, windows-xp, prefetch

Are there known ways to extract/restore data from a .pf prefetch file like

```
c:\windows(XP)\Prefetch\WINWORD.EXE-2......5.pf      (office/word 2007)
```

Or

```
Prefetch\WINRAR.EXE-3......8.pf
```

We thought it was saved but accidentally clicked 'cancel' on writing changes to the winrar archive...

Comment: What are you hoping to recover from it?

Comment: the text of the word file that was meant to be saved in the same minute these two files appeared.  thanks:)

Comment: Might be helpful: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/win_prefetch_view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but prefetch files only contain a trace of the file accesses made by a program, not the contents of the accesses themselves. Also only the first 10 seconds of an application's activity is traced, as it's meant only to speed up loading times.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefetcher